# Где можно найти хорошее пособие по верстке сайтов?

Tags: html, css, psd

Всем добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти хорошее пособие (видео и не только) по верстке сайтов? В основном верстка из PSD макета в HTML/CSS.

Comment: Поработать верстальщиком практикантом несколько месяцев: получите незаменимый опыт который не описан не в одной книге.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/202408/

Answer (score 1):

[psd2cms.ru](http://psd2cms.ru)

Answer (score 1):

На этом сайте есть много хороших рецептов для CSS, также есть видеоуроки.

http://www.webmasters.by/